# Sitecore Items conversion from version 6.5 to version 6.6

Tags: sitecore

I'm in the middle of developing a website using Sitecore 6.5 and when my company knew that Sitecore released version 6.6 they want to use the new version instead for the project, Is there a way to convert my Items created using sitecore 6.5(webform) to sitecore 6.6(mvc) so I wont redo my work?

Answer (score 5):

General content items are not affected by switching to MVC .. it would be any presentation items that you would need to update if you did make a move to MVC. As @JayS says MVC is not mandatory and you can actually mix MVC and Webforms layouts within the solution so if you wanted to convert to MVC slowly over time it would be a possibility.

Just wanted to note that there is no such thing as 'recommended releases' any more (see: http://sdn.sitecore.net/support/versioning%20policy.aspx). Lots of customers already using 6.6 in production. The upgrade from 6.5 -> 6.6 should be straightforward (but this obviously depends on the complexity of your solution).

Comment: Really? No more recommended releases? My bad.  I was going off the release notes for 6.6, which were updated in mid-january, and still state that it is not the recommended release.  http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC66.aspx#660update3.  That's good to know!

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, you do not need to use MVC in 6.6 if you do not want to.  John West has a [blog about the installer](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/11/Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-6-6-Installer-Enables-MVC-by-Default.aspx) and how it enables MVC.  You should be able to port your existing solution up to 6.6 relatively easily, but if you wish to take advantage of MVC you'll need to alter your solution.

Note, I believe that Sitecore has not marked 6.6 as a recommended release, so you may wish to inform your company of that.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Stephen for pointing out that Sitecore has discontinued using the recommended release tagging.  Some of their documentation online still needs to be updated regarding this :)